# How to find out application is using object reference in cache?

Tags: python, caching, reference, del

I find it hard to explain my problem as the problem is not within the code itself. If you need more input to understand the following better, please let me know.

I'm using ArcGIS to call a bunch of python scripts, one after another. The scripts use the same class by importing it, or inherit from it. To initialize the class I often use the same name. I have no idea how the communication between ArcGIS and python is implemented. But I noticed that my scripts are not always behaving like they should. I suppose that the reference to the object still exists (even though the script the object was created with has finished) when I call the second script.

First of all: How can I make sure my suspicion is true? 
Secondly, if this is the case: is it a good idea to destroy all references to all objects using `del` or `__del__`? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Trace tracing your code and walking through it with a debugger? Quickest way to tell if it's accessing correct code. [Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)

If you read the documentation, what you want to do is use a break point to make sure code reaches that point in code.
This is the syntax with the debugger.

```
  b(reak) [[filename:]lineno | function[, condition]]
```

Comment: As I said, the problem is not within the code. If I run and test it with IDLE for example it is all good. ArcGIS seems to hold references to objects (like my classes) in memory but how do test this?

Comment: Restart the software, if that fails restart your computer.

Comment: - The code may not have any fault if but your software is using an old copy of the code it will stand out and be obvious when walking through it. So yes, your code is fine-- but walking through each code one line at a time forces most software to use the most up to date code, not outdated, possibly cached data.